# Responsive packery grid

Tags: javascript, css, packery

I am about to use packery or a hardcoded variant if it doesn't work. But I want to use something to position absolute a grid, but keep it responsive -- not that items fall down to compensate, but using percentages retain their positions.

//latest jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/q4kp3z80/1/

this is roughly the grid I am trying to build with fixed widths -- so rather than the blocks falling down to compensate for a resize I want to keep the blocks intact but just adjust the widths of each block --- so try and change the fixed widths for percentages and keep the layout intact -- until it hits a threshold-- then go stacked for mobile
I have a grid block like this

//HTML

```
<h1>Packery - animate responsive item size</h1>



<div class="grid">

  <div class="grid-item height5 width2">
    Item 1  w: 254 h: 407
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item height2 width">
    Item 2 w: 232 h: 228
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item height2 width5">
    Item 3 w: 286 h: 228
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item height2 width5">
    Item 4 w: 286 h: 228
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item height2 width">
    Item 5 w: 286 h: 228
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item height3 width7">
    Item 6 w: 370 h: 260
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item height3 width8">
    Item 7 w: 410 h: 260
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item height3 width6">
    Item 8 w: 306 h: 260
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item height4 width2">
    Item 9 w: 254 h: 275
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item height width9">
    Item 10 w: 548 h: 189
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item height width3">
    Item 11 w: 272 h: 189
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item height width4">
    Item 12 w: 266 h: 189
  </div>
</div>
```

//CSS

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

/* force scrollbar */
html { overflow-y: scroll; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.grid {
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

/* item is invisible, but used for layout */


.grid-item {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;
}



.width{
  width: 232px;
}
.width2{
  width: 254px;
}
.width3{
  width: 272px;
}
.width4{
  width: 266px;
}
.width5{
  width: 286px;
}
.width6{
  width: 306px;
}
.width7{
  width: 370px;
}
.width8{
  width: 410px;
}
.width9{
  width: 548px;
}



/*height*/
.height{
  height: 189px;
}
.height2{
  height: 228px;
}
.height3{
  height: 260px;
}
.height4{
  height: 275px;
}
.height5{
  height: 407px;
}
```

JS

```
// external js: packery.pkgd.js

var $grid = $('.grid').packery({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  gutter: 10
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: standard packery - but the blocks fall to compensate -- https://jsfiddle.net/7xzd92s5/107/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q4kp3z80/1/  -- here it is

Comment: this may have done it -- turning the widths into percentages -- http://jsfiddle.net/q4kp3z80/10/

Comment: is there a way of replicating this though - without having to use packery?